# How do you prove that $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ is not an elementary function? In general how do you prove such a thing?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I already know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ and by the fundamental theorem of calculus this could be computed by its antiderivative function but it`s impossible to find.

I ask my teachers for proofs for this but they always tell me to investigate in some obscure book. I also tried to look for an idea of the proof (what techniques are used or a sketch of it) but I can`t find any.

Comment: This is because it is a genuinely difficult result, both to precisely state and to prove.

Comment: It is less that it is impossible to find and more that it is impossible to express in a "nice" way. E.g. I can tell you that one antiderivative is: $$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$Or that one antiderivative is: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\cdot(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$$It's just that neither is analytically very useful. There is something called the "Risch algorithm" I believe, that will show if it is "nicely expressible". Mindlack's comment sums the issue up

Comment: The field that deals with this is called [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory). You may have a look at this: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~adebray/lecture_notes/u19_differential_Galois_theory.pdf

Comment: Well, they're telling you to look at obscure books because you're really about to open Pandora's box here. The keyword is "Differential Galois Theory". I know people with PhD's who have never heard of this. I'm absolutely no expert in this, but the first reference that comes to mind is *Andy R. Magid, Lectures on Differential Galois Theory, University Lecture Series Volume: 7; AMS (1994)*